# how to import and use a trained acoustic model in a java sphinx4 project

Tags: java, arabic, speech, sphinx4

i need help in making a program in java language that is a speech recognition program i have a trained acoustic model i want to ask u that how can i use this trained acoustic model in my program i am new to speech recognition platform and i want to work in netbeans editor so please give me instructions to test my acoustic model like if i input the same audio as used in model then it should play the audio stored in model hope u understand my question and i am working on arabic speech to speech recognition 
plz help me as early as possible 
thankx in advance

Comment: Your question is unreadable. Instead of hoping that people understand you, please use punctuation marks, commas and, in general, proper grammar.

Answer (score 0):

Using a trained acoustic model simply requires a configuration file change. 
See http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/sphinx4/doc/UsingSphinxTrainModels.html